# What is "Signature" in javap -v

Tags: java, maven

Using javap -v, I get an output like this:

```
Classfile /C:/temp/classcompare/PartnerRolle.class
  Last modified 09.12.2016; size 2880 bytes
  MD5 checksum 2deeeaa2734ac86f673bba871c05a997
  Compiled from "PartnerRolle.java"
public final class de.continentale.vs.common.model.enums.PartnerRolle extends java.lang.Enum<de.continentale.vs.common.model.enums.PartnerRolle>
  Signature: #110                         // Ljava/lang/Enum<Lde/continentale/vs/common/model/enums/PartnerRolle;>;
  SourceFile: "PartnerRolle.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER, ACC_ENUM
```

What does "Signature #110" mean?

Background: I am getting different class files for the same java source when compiling with Ant and Maven (same Java version). I am trying to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javap -v` is the equivalent of `javap -verbose`.

Class file format is defined in the JVM specification.
If you look at part [4.7.9. The signature attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9) you'll find the definition of `Signature`

> The Signature attribute is a fixed-length attribute in the attributes table of a ClassFile, field_info, or method_info structure. A Signature attribute records a signature for a class, interface, constructor, method, or field whose declaration in the Java programming language uses type variables or parameterized types. [...]
>
> The Signature attribute has the following format:
>
> Signature_attribute {
>           u2 attribute_name_index;
>           u4 attribute_length;
>           u2 signature_index;
>       }
>
> The items of the Signature_attribute structure are as follows:
>
> attribute_name_index
>
> The value of the attribute_name_index item must be a valid index into the constant_pool table. The constant_pool entry at that index must be a CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure (§4.4.7) representing the string "Signature".
>
> attribute_length
>
> The value of the attribute_length item of a Signature_attribute structure must be two.
>
> signature_index
>
> The value of the signature_index item must be a valid index into the constant_pool table. The constant_pool entry at that index must be
>   a CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure (§4.4.7) representing a class signature
>   if this Signature attribute is an attribute of a ClassFile structure;
>   a method signature if this Signature attribute is an attribute of a
>   method_info structure; or a field signature otherwise.

`Signature #110` means that your signature is stored at index 110 in the constant pool table.

Answer (score 1):

"Signature" is the generic type signature of the corresponding class or method. "Signature: #110" means that the signature for this class is stored as constant pool entry #110 in the .class file.

The format of the strings used as values for the "Signature" attribute is described in the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.4).